# Is there a link between level of abstraction and use of numbers?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, education, philosophy

One of my friend who stopped studying maths in high school told me once

> You study maths, can you help me fill my tax forms?

In her mind, advancing in maths studies implied manipulating an increasing amount of numbers. The reality I faced was the contrary: I dropped numbers for some more abstract notions (i.e. letters and symbols).

I wonder if a (putative) link between abstraction and use of numbers has been investigated. For instance, can we say that one area of mathematics is more abstract than another one just because it uses less numbers in its formulation? Or, is this particular domain of maths became more complex as it uses less numbers? One possible metric I think of would be the number of numbers per "mathematical" line.

*This question may not be within the scope of math.stackexchange, but I didn't find a more suitable site. Thanks!*

Comment: If you want a taste of the kinds of things students of advanced mathematics are most preoccupied with, just take a gander at the kinds of questions being asked here on this forum. One thing to notice is that the emphasis is much more on the behavior of functions and relations between sets of objects, rather than being primarily focused on the objects themselves.

Comment: The lack of being able to compute things like $5\times 7$ in their head is proverbial for some math "geniuses", whereas others multiply 10 digit numbers for entertainment purposes. And in some cases (I recommend to attend a talk by Don Zagier to witness this) manipulating and/or memorizing multidigit numbers is even part of the high level math "job". - But tax forms?!